# Is there a name for practise of avoiding using programing langue types?

Tags: design-patterns

I try to convince coworkers to stop writing code like this (example in java):

```
class Person {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String surname;
}
```

and write code like this:

```
class Person {
    PersonId id;
    PersonName name;
    PersonSurname surname;
}
```

Basically, I want to avoid overusing Strings', Longs' and use dedicated types that correspond to a domain. This is not a new concept, methodology or practise (however you call it), so it probably already have a name. There probably are many people who have already written pros and cons of such approach, but I cannot find any, because I do not know what to look for.

Comment: It's usually called ['stringly typed'](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).

Comment: Personally, I think the first example is fine. I would not call that stringly-typed programming so long as the `Person` object is being passed around and not its individual fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the name of that practise is `Avoiding Primitive Obsession`.

According to this [article](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession):

> The Smell: Primitive Obsession is using primitive data types to represent domain ideas. For example, we use a String to represent a message, an Integer to represent an amount of money, or a Struct/Dictionary/Hash to represent a specific object.
>
> The Fix: Typically, we introduce a ValueObject in place of the primitive data.
>
> The Tools: Some languages make this easier or harder on you.

In languages like C# and Java it can be painful to create hundred of tiny types just wrapping a simple string or int. For example you will have a lot of classes like this:

```
class PersonName {
    public String value;
    public PersonName(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

But in [ML languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) like F#, it is trivial to create simple wrapper types:

```
type PersonName = PersonName of string
```

Some good articles on the topic:

- https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365017/when-is-primitive-obsession-not-a-code-smell
- http://codemonkeyism.com/never-never-never-use-string-in-java-or-at-least-less-often/
- https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/